# How can I uninstall the globally installed "create-strapi-app"?

Tags: yarnpkg, strapi

I moved to a new computer and need to revive old projects (mostly vue, quasar). To do so I run `yarn install`, then `yarn global add @quasar/cli`. After the second command I get an error:

```
error create-strapi-app@4.0.6: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.22.0 <=16.x.x". Got "18.12.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

I did install the strapi cli in a previous project, but I thought that I removed it again using `yarn global remove strapi`:

```
> yarn global remove strapi
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
```

So I wonder where the error comes from. I checked the global dir (`yarn global dir`), but there is no strapi cli neither any strapi package at all.

How can I remove the `create-strapi-app` error?
(I do not want to change the node version; I want to remove the error.)

Comment: And of course, 5 minutes after posting I find the answer. I had to look for "@strapi", with a prefixed "@"; then I also had to remove and "create-strapi-app" entries from the global package.js and yarn.lock files. No it is working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to edit the file (macOS)

> /Users/[username]/.config/yarn/global/package.json

(On Windows, the path is something like this: %LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn/config/global)

then delete string create-strapi-app
[image]

then check the global list of package

> yarn global list

after these steps, everything should install without problems